# Why does some utf-8 chars are not working in Windows but inside of browsers?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, fonts

I am using Windows 7 and Google Chrome and I can see all these icons:

```
   ★    ♥   ♠   ✈
   ☺    ☻   ♫   ♪
   ✔    ✖   ♂   ♀
   ☢    ✡   ☞   ☯
```

But when I try to rename a bookmark in Google Chrome this icon works: `♥`
but this not: `★`

Instead of displaying the star, I just see a longish rectangle:

[image]

Does anybody knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font used in the GUI does not contain this glyph, so it just displays a placeholder.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The font in Google Chrome UI is __Segoe UI__ (on Windows 7, on Windows XP it is __Tahoma__)

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that's because there are 110,000 characters in the [Unicode standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and all fonts have varying coverage of it.

For example [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) covers just 38,917.

To make sure if that's the case you could find out what your Windows uses as a system font to display folder names (or is it Chrome folders on your screenshot? then finding out the font used could be harder) and try to set it as a font that your browser displays pages with.

As your comment to the other answer shows you've succeeded in proving my guess, congrats!